# pshape processing multiple

Tags: svg, processing, shapes

I'm trying to make a PShape SVG multipy. I want a new shape created every time a variable (that I'm importing from a CSV file) changes. I tried using a `for`, but it doesn`t respect the variable range I'm giving it, it just creates as many SVGs as it wants. Basically what I'm trying to do is that if the variable indicates there are 21 data between an X rage, draw 21 copies of the SVG in a fixed distance between one and other.

```
Table table;

PShape tipi2;
PShape tipi3;


void setup() {

  size (1875, 871);
  table = loadTable("WHO.csv", "header");
  tipi2 = loadShape("tipi-02.svg");


}


void draw() {

  background(0);


  for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {

    int hale = row.getInt("Healthy life expectancy (HALE) at birth (years) both sexes");


  }
    tipi2.disableStyle();


noStroke();

 for( int i = 0 ;i<=1800;i=i+33){


 pushMatrix();

  translate(0,89.5);

       if(hale > 40 && hale < 60){

shape(tipi2,i,0);

popMatrix();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you clean up your indentation for readability?

Comment: @LauraFlorez Can you post the .svg (as code snippet) and .csv(as link) file to make it easier for us to test ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that couple things that could be improved in your current code:

- the `hale` variable's visibility (or scope) is only within this loop: `for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {`
- the drawing styles (noStroke()/disableStyle(),etc.) don't change much therefore could e set once in `setup()` rather than multiple times a second in `draw()`
- you could move the for loop from 0 to 1800 inside the `for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {` loop, but that might not be very efficient:

Here's what I mean:

```
Table table;

PShape tipi2;
PShape tipi3;


void setup() {

  size (1875, 871);
  table = loadTable("WHO.csv", "header");
  tipi2 = loadShape("tipi-02.svg");

  //this styles could be set once in setup, rather than multiple times in draw(); 
  tipi2.disableStyle();
  noStroke();

  background(0);


  for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {

    int hale = row.getInt("Healthy life expectancy (HALE) at birth (years) both sexes");

    for ( int i = 0; i<=1800; i=i+33) {

      pushMatrix();

      translate(0, 89.5);
      //hale is visible within this scope, but not outside the for loop
      if (hale > 40 && hale < 60) {

        shape(tipi2, i, 0);

      }
      //popMatrix(); should be called the same amount of times as pushMatrix
      popMatrix();
    }

  }
}


void draw() {


}
```